# Create TS Array Custom Types?

Tags: javascript, typescript

Is it possible to do something like this to define a custom Companies Array type?:

```
export interface Company {
  name: string;
}

export interface Companies: Array<Company> {

}
```

it doesn't seem to like my syntax for **Companies**.

Or does this not make any sense to try to do at all?

Comment: is this what you mean `interface Companies extends Array<Company> {}`?

Comment: You could go with alias: `type Companies = Array<Company>;`

Comment: maybe, that's probably what I infer.  I guess making this would allow my TS to be a little shorter than specifying Array<Company> all over the place in my code?

Comment: it sounds like both of you are showing me a way to basically kinda do the same thing right?  And benefit being that it's cleaner to use in my code as well when I use that type or interface rather than specify Array<Company> all over the place right?

Comment: please do not vote to close this, this has a valid answer, both of you showed examples of that

Comment: just in case you want to have a shorter definition, you may go with `Company[]`

Comment: thanks all for your comments, extremely useful to a n00b TS guy.  Glad this wasn't closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you simply want an array of companies, you can use either one of these:

```
type Companies = Company[]
type Companies = Array<Company>
```

Alternatively, you don't even need to define a type alias and can just use `Company[]` or `Array<Company>`.

However, if you want to declare additional properties on the array, you can extend `Array<Company>`:

```
interface Companies extends Array<Company> {
  foo: string
  bar: number
}
```

To make such an object, you can use one of these:

```
declare const normalArray: Company[]

const companies1: Companies = Object.assign(normalArray, {foo: '', bar: 0})

const companies2 = normalArray as Companies
companies2.foo = ''
companies2.bar = 0
```